# How do you retrieve tweets that happened within the last week?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'd like to find a technique to search for tweets that where sent during the whole day this past week.

I have used Tweepy before to scrape live tweets but not getting old ones. I'd like to use a Python library to do this and preferably not SnapBird.